# simpleJWT confirm password field

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-framework-simplejwt

I'm creating a small app that uses simpleJWT. I want the user to retype their password when registering. Currently, I'm sending data like this

```
{
    "email":"test",
    "user_name":"test3",
    "password":"b12@wsqp"
}
```

But what I want to validate is

```
{
    "email":"test",
    "user_name":"test3",
    "password":"b12@wsqp",
    "password2":"b12@wsqp"
}
```

What i have now is

```py
class CustomUserCreate(APIView):

    permission_classes = (AllowAny,)

    def post(self, request):
        
        reg_serializer = RegisterUserSerializer(data=request.data)
        if reg_serializer.is_valid():
            new_user = reg_serializer.save()
            if new_user:
                return Response(status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(reg_serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

class RegisterUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('email', 'user_name', 'password')

        extra_kwargs = {'password': {'write_only': True}}
        

        def create(self, validated_data):
            password = validated_data.pop('password', None)
            instance = self.Meta.model(**validated_data)

            if password is not None:
                instance.set_password(password)

            instance.save()
            return instance
```

So my guess is to do

```py
class RegisterUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('email', 'user_name', 'password1', 'password2')

        extra_kwargs = {'password': {'write_only': True}, 'password2':{'write_only': True}}
        

        def create(self, validated_data):
            password1 = validated_data.pop('password1', None)
            password2 = validated_data.pop('password2', None)
            instance = self.Meta.model(**validated_data)

            if password1 is not None and password2 is not None:
                if password1 == password2:
                    instance.set_password(password)
                else:
                    #return some error

            instance.save()
            return instance
```

How can I validate if the password are matching?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can  validate the two passwords fields with serializers **`validate(self, attrs) method`** like this  :

```
def validate(self, attrs):
    if attrs['password1'] != attrs['password2']:
        raise serializers.ValidationError({"password": "Password fields didn't match."})

    return attrs
```

in your case change your **RegisterUserSerializer** class  like this :

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from rest_framework.validators import UniqueValidator
from django.contrib.auth.password_validation import validate_password


class RegisterUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    
    password1 = serializers.CharField(write_only=True,  validators=[validate_password])
    password2 = serializers.CharField(write_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('email','user_name', 'password1', 'password2')
        

    def validate(self, attrs):
        if attrs['password1'] != attrs['password2']:
            raise serializers.ValidationError({"password": "Password fields didn't match."})

        return attrs

    def create(self, validated_data):
        user = User.objects.create(
            username=validated_data['user_name'],
            email=validated_data['email'],
            
        )

        
        user.set_password(validated_data['password'])
        user.save()

        return user
```

Comment: when im running your code I get Got a `TypeError` when calling `User.objects.create()`. This may be because you have a writable field on the serializer class that is not a valid argument to `User.objects.create()`. You may need to make the field read-only, or override the RegisterUserSerializer.create() method to handle this correctly.

Comment: password=attrs.get('password')
password2=attrs.pop('password2')  - I've added this into validate()